# How to align createMaterialTopTabNavigator to the Right

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Currently my items are all to the left as they should be by default. I can not seem to move it to the right side. For reference, I have attached an image

https://ibb.co/fYFPMFJ

I have already tried styling it with `tabStyle` and using `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` `alignItems: 'flex-end'` `flexDirection: 'row'`, `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`

Here is the code:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

    ރިޕޯޓު: {screen: MainScreenCategoryTabNavigator, params:{categoryID: 1004}},
    ދީން: {screen: MainScreenCategoryTabNavigator, params:{categoryID: 1003}},
    ސިޔާސީ: {screen: MainScreenCategoryTabNavigator, params:{categoryID: 1002}},
    ޙަބަރު: {screen: MainScreenTabNavigator, params:{categoryID: 1000}},

},
    {
        initialRouteName:'ޙަބަރު',
        lazy: true,
        tabBarOptions: {
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'MV_Waheed',
                fontWeight: "200"
            },
            tabStyle: {
                width: 60,
                textAlign: 'right'
            },
        }
    },
);
```

Like I mentioned above, and the reference to the image attached, I would like to move the tabs to the right instead of left. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The problem for me was that I could not align it to the right. I removed the width and that solved my problem. That was all that needed to be done

Answer (score 0):

One of the variants it's to use your own component as a tabBar. In this way it's easier to customize it as you wish.
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

```
const TabBarComponent = (props) => (<BottomTabBar {...props} />);

const TabScreens = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    tabBarComponent: props =>
      <TabBarComponent
        {...props}
        style={{ borderTopColor: '#605F60' }}
      />,
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi. Is it not possible to shift the navigation to top? I want it to be on top bar and that method does not allow to position to top

Comment: There are a coiuple of problems using bottom tab navigation. I can't use swipe. I can't position it to top. Is this resolvable or do I have to take another approach?

Comment: you can use createMaterialTopTabNavigator instead

Comment: Thats the problem. How do I align it? I am already using material top navigator when I posted the question. The docs are a bit confusing. I’m not sure how to align it. The question I posted already uses material top navigator. I just cant align the tabs to the right

Comment: Do you use default component as a container or your own one?

Comment: I used default. I do not know how to use materialTopTabNavigation with custom components. That is actually what I asked in the first place. Maybe a good example with my original question may help because I already have everything you need in the question. I just don’t know the components setup part

Answer (score 0):

If you created your navigation using this other way:
`const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();`
Style using the `tabBarItemStyle` and `tabBarIndicatorStyle`
The code now look like:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
     tabBarIndicatorStyle:{ left:200 },
     tabBarItemStyle:{ width:100, left:200 }}}>

       <Tab.Screen  name='screen1' component={Screen1} />
       <Tab.Screen name='screen2' component={Screen2} />

  </Tab.Navigator>
```